# 多段サーバー構成でscpを使いたい

Tags: scp

[クライアントA] -- [サーバB] -- [サーバC]
のようなネットワーク構成があります。クライアントAからサーバCには直接アクセスはできません。
このような構成の場合、クライアントAからサーバCにscpでファイルを置こうとしたら、
1. クライアントAからサーバBにscpでファイルを置く
2. クライアントAからサーバBにsshでログイン
3. サーバBからサーバCにscpでファイルを置く
4. サーバBのファイルを削除
という手順を行なっています。

非常に面倒なので、クライアントAの操作のみでサーバCに(サーバBを経由して)ファイルを置けないかと思っています。

いい方法をご存知の方は、ご教示いただけると幸いです。

Comment: Stack Exchange 上のサイト ServerFault における類似質問です: ["How do I do Multihop SCP transfers?"](https://serverfault.com/q/37629/412043)

Answer (score 1):

ぱっと思いつく方法は、2通りあります。

1. ご提示の2～4の手順をsshコマンドで実行するスクリプトを作成する。
2. ProxyCommandを用いて、多段sshを実行してみる

おそらく、やりたいことは2の方が近いと思いますので、実現するための参考サイトを
ご提示します。

https://dev.classmethod.jp/beginners/direct-ssh-by-proxycommand/
https://qiita.com/S-T/items/18af2bfcc4e5a72202da

ただ、サーバー間の設定が適切でないとはまりそうなので、注意して実施してください。

Comment: OpenSSH 7.3以降だと、 `ProxyJump` という機能も使えます。

Comment: 補足有難うございます。勉強になりました

Answer (score 1):

どれか1つをクライアントAの`~/.ssh/config`に追記します。

`ProxyCommand`を用いる場合その1:

```
Host <サーバB>
  User <BのログインID>

Host <サーバC>
  User <CのログインID>
  ProxyCommand ssh <サーバB> nc %h %p
```

`ProxyCommand`を用いる場合その2(5.4以降で利用可):

```
Host <サーバB>
  User <BのログインID>

Host <サーバC>
  User <CのログインID>
  ProxyCommand ssh -W %h:%p <サーバB>
```

`ProxyJump`を用いる場合(7.3以降で利用可):

```
Host <サーバB>
  User <BのログインID>

Host <サーバC>
  User <CのログインID>
  ProxyJump <サーバB>
```

---

実行例:

```
scp myfile <サーバC>:./myfile
```

参考:
[OpenSSH/Cookbook/Proxies and Jump Hosts - Wikibooks, open books for an open world](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/OpenSSH/Cookbook/Proxies_and_Jump_Hosts#Jump_Hosts_--_Passing_Through_a_Gateway_or_Two)

man では ssh(1), ssh_config(5) が該当するかと思います。